# jquery ajax problem - data length

Tags: jquery

I'm using netbeans with tomcat 6 , I have inside my program jquery ajax call , 
I have a with this call and i found that when sending inside the ajax data more then ~7000 charecters this problem accurs.

Is there a limit for the data length? 
If so is it from the ajax? from netbeans? tomact?

Any help will be appritiated!

Thank's In Advance.

**UPDATE**: i'm using post method.

This the connector part of my server.xml:

```
 <Connector URIEncoding="utf-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="0"/>
```

I'm getting http error 400 bad request.

Comment: What method are you trying to send the data? GET or POST? GET has a limitation of 255 characters. while POST is unlimited.

Comment: @Coding-Freak: GET hasn't a limitation of 255 characters. It's browser dependant, for example for IE : `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use the GET method, you'll be limited on how many characters you use.
To be more awful, this limit is browser dependant.

Prefer using POST method which should not be limited

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a maximum post size which can be configured.
Take a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/ajp.html and search for **maxPostSize**